# Replace part of string matched with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some regex to match Imgur URLS (I think it's right, please tell me if it's not):

```
http://(?:i\.imgur\.com/(?.*?)\.(?:jpg|png|gif)|imgur\.com/(?:gallery/)?(?.*))$
```

What I want to do, is search a document for instances that match that regex, but the replace the string `imgur` without changing anything around it. How can I do this with Javascript?

Comment: Both of those just discuss matching URLs, rather than replacing a substring of them

Comment: FYI Added variation at the bottom to handle your revised specs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript's replace method.

Just use the regex `\imgur\g` as the parameter to replace.

See examples at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp. You will likely want to see the first one in the "More examples" section.

Comment: I don't want to match `imgur` when it is not used in the context of a URL. So for example, the sentence "Click here to visit Imgur" should not change.